# Add new fields - prefix, suffix - magento 1,9

Tags: checkout

I need to create 2 fields in checkout.

I want not to create a new fields in db (the web site is online).

I would like to use prefix and suffix.

If in back-end this fields is set "visible", the fields is visible in checkout. I would like to set "disable" in back-end and insert this string in checkout:

```
<input type="text" id="billing:prefix" name="billing [prefix]" title="Prefix" class="input-text validate-email" value="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getAddress()->getPrefix())?>">
```

but the value is not registered in db.
The value is registered in db only the fields is set enable in back-end.

There is a way to register the value prefix and suffix with  disable in back-end?

can you help me?

Is there another way to use the fields prefix and suffix with disable in the back-end?

Thanks

Comment: What is the reason not to use the Magento default funcionality, i.e. enable the fields if you want to use them?

Comment: I need 2 extra fields